# Execute select with two tables on SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android 3.1 application.

I have the following tables:

```
FormBlock
---------
FormId  (INTEGER) FOREIGN KEY TO Form.id
BlockId (INTEGER) FOREIGN KEY TO Block.id

Block
----------
id          (INTEGER) PRIMARY KEY
name        (TEXT)    NOT NULL
orderInForm (INTEGER) NOT NULL
```

And I want to do the following select:

```
SELECT block.blockId, block.name, block.orderInForm FROM Block, FormBlock WHERE FormBlock.FormId = 1 AND block.blockId = FormBlock.blockId;
```

How can I do that select statement with SQLiteDatabase.query(...) or `rawQuery()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    block.blockId, block.name, block.orderInForm
FROM
    Block, FormBlock 
WHERE
    FormBlock.FormId = 1 AND block.blockId = FormBlock.blockId;
```

as `query` is

```
String table = "Block, FormBlock";
String[] columns = new String[] { "block.blockId", "block.name", "block.orderInForm" };
String where = "FormBlock.FormId = 1 AND block.blockId = FormBlock.blockId";
Cursor result = db.query(table, columns, where, null, null, null, null);
```

if the `1` is dynamic then

```
int formId = 1;
String table = "Block, FormBlock";
String[] columns = new String[] { "block.blockId", "block.name", "block.orderInForm" };
String where = "FormBlock.FormId = ? AND block.blockId = FormBlock.blockId";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(formId) };
Cursor result = db.query(table, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Block WHERE id IN
                  (SELECT BlockId FROM FormBlock WHERE FormId = 1)";

Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
```